# I have "network" location provider but got : Provider "network" unknown, why?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-location

I have a `AndroidTestCase` , I run my test in real device with Android 4.1.2 OS.

```
public class MyLocationTest extends AndroidTestCase{
  private String TEST_PROVIDER = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

  @Override
  public void setUp() throws Exception{
     super.setUp();

     mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getContext()
                                 .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

     //I check what are the providers available, 
     //the log shows me: network, gps, passive
     List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getAllProviders();
     for(int i=0; i<providers.size(); i++){
        Log.i("DEBUG", "Provider: "+providers.get(i));
     }

    //The following code raise Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider "network" unknown
    mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(TEST_PROVIDER, true);
    mLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus(TEST_PROVIDER, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
  }

}
```

In the `setUp()` phase of my above test case, I checked the available providers, and got **"network"** in log. Then, I invoke `setTestProviderEnabled(TEST_PROVIDER, true)` , but I got Exception: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  Provider "network" unknown**

I don't understand why?? I have "network" provider but I got this exception...

By the way, I have enabled "Allow mocked location" on device, also have wifi network connected.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a mock location provider and add it to the active providers.

```
mLocationManager.addTestProvider(TEST_PROVIDER, false, 
false, false, false, false, true, true, 0, 5);
// your code
mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(TEST_PROVIDER, true);
```

Hope this helps.